# Chrome not showing OPTIONS requests in Network tab

Tags: google-chrome, cors, google-chrome-devtools, preflight

My web client application is setting HTTP POST requests via fetch API.

I see that OPTIONS preflight requests are sent via debugging proxy (Charles Proxy), but they are not displayed in Google Chrome Developer Tools\Network tab.

I don't have any filters setup on the network tab. I remember OPTIONS requests being visible there, but not anymore. How do I bring them back?

Answer (score 167, accepted):

You'll need to go to: `chrome://flags/#out-of-blink-cors`, **disable** the flag, and restart Chrome.

This is an expected behavior change according to:
https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=995740#c1

I originally came across this via:
https://support.google.com/chrome/thread/11089651?hl=en

Comment: This worked. But I couldn't find in the linked pages what this "out-of-blink-cors" setting does. Blink is chrome engine name - so what component does cors instead of it? And what has effectively changed for normal websites that are not chrome extensions?

Comment: I would imagine that the handling of cors got moved into the engine - a lower level than devtools has access to. But you can disable that optimization.

Comment: This behavior will turn newcomer devs life so much harder. This is basically hiding the answer to errors.

Comment: Chrome 79+ no longer shows preflight CORS requests. You can use for example Firefox to see it.

Comment: Good news from the Chrome implementor who worked on the related code: See the answer at https://stackoverflow.com/a/62590759/441757 *“Chrome 83 implements the CORS preflight DevTools support again in a security preserved way. So you can monitor the CORS preflight requests as you could do before the Out-Of-Blink/Renderer CORS”*

Comment: @Ubeogesh search for 'cors' only and you will find the option easily.

Comment: As @GZH suggest in the answer below, you can use the "Other" tab to see CORS pre-flight OPTIONS requests.

Comment: This option is not available on my Chrome v121

Answer (score 77):

As of 2021 in CHROME the OPTIONS request is visible in the NETWORK tab filter OTHER requests

To see it together with XHR just CTRL+click and pick the request filters you want to see.

UPDATE (April 17) Chrome Version 90.0.4430.72 has made the options requests hidden again :(

Comment: What is going on with chrome? This is the 4th toggle of showing these requests in the last ~10 versions. I can't keep up.

Comment: to add on top of this, the preflights seems like being cached. Here we go incognito...

Comment: On the advice of others on this page I've just switched to Firefox for this and with no extra config I can quite easily see the `OPTIONS` request. Taking on board the answer from @Takashi Toyoshima, this makes me wonder whether Firefox is less secure or whether the Chromium team are just unable to work out how to do what Mozilla have done.

Comment: on Chrome 119 I see `OPTIONS` requests. What I'm trying to figure out is if the timing of these show up as the "queueing" span in the subsequent POST. (contrary to google's docs)..

Answer (score 29):

Chrome 81 does not seem to display anything even after changing the option and restarting on my computer.

As an alternative solution, I started to use Firefox and its Network tab for development.

[image]

https://getfirefox.com

Comment: I'm using Chrome 81 and changing the flag as suggested by [jms](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57631040/1128918) worked.

Comment: @GustavoStraube Hmmm. Are you on which operating system?

Comment: MacOS Mojave (10.14.6)

Comment: I was seeing this behaviour when testing a site behind basic http auth. Even if you're logged in on another tab the preflight request will always fail (v84)

Answer (score 17):

I'm Takashi from Chromium Project, and drove the Out-Of-Blink/Render CORS project.

The project intended to introduce a process isolated CORS implementation for better security and privacy, and many of new network related features rely on this new implementation. Unfortunately we temporarily disabled preflight support in DevTools as it turned out continuing to support it weakens security and privacy. Sorry for inconvenience during this period.

Good news is now Chrome 83 implements the CORS preflight DevTools support again in a security preserved way. So you can monitor the CORS preflight requests as you could do before the Out-Of-Blink/Renderer CORS.

Best,

Comment: I'm running latest chrome on macOS and still don't see the OPTIONS in the network inspector. Help?

Comment: Chrome 83.0.4103.116 (Mac OS) - still no pre-flight information visible in the network panel.  Is there some flag that needs to be turned on?

Comment: Chrome 83.0.4103.116 (Official Build) (64-bit) on MacOs still not showing pre-flight for me too. And the experimental out-of-blink-cors option is no longer available.

Comment: Can you try the following page?
http://yuri.twintail.org/chrome/cors/preflight.html

1) Open DevTools
2) Click the "make cors fetch" button
3) You will see two requests for 918322_21.cgi, one is failing actual request, and the other is 200 for the preflight.

Note: if the request hits the CORS preflight cache, we don't show anything as Chrome does not send the preflight. "Disable cache" option in the DevTools is expected to mitigate this problem as preflight cache is also disabled with this option,.

Comment: ok, it looks my test case also does not work for the affected people. this may be a user-profile dependent issue and I'm investigating what conditions cause this.
If you see this problem, could you visit following thread and share your issues?
https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1102742

Comment: For me running Chrome 84/Win10, OPTIONS requests show up in the Network tab if you select the 'All' filter, but don't if you select the 'XHR' filter. Which is annoying because then I have to wade through dozens of other requests I don't care about. Any idea why you can't show them in both places?

Comment: On Toyoshima's site I see the console error `Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: The 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header has a value 'http://alt-yuri.twintail.org' that is not equal to the supplied origin.` and I can see the OPTIONS request in the Network tab.  However, on another site I get a different error: `No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.` and I CANNOT see the OPTIONS request.  (Chrome 85.0.4183.102 OSX)

Comment: Would be nice to see the OPTIONS request in the network tab even if no header is present!

Comment: CORS preflight (OPTIONS request) is not always sent even if the request is cross-origin one.
See MDN document as a readable reference. Preflight is omitted for simple requests. As long as the preflight is sent, current Chrome will show the request in DevTools network tab.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Preflight_request

Comment: @ChrisTybur Yeah dude, that was it :)