# Sec-Fetch-Mode instead of Preflight

Tags: firebase, express, axios, google-cloud-functions, sec-fetch-mode

I created login FE and finished it.
And as per usual my goto for ajax was Axios. My code is as follows.

```
const baseUrl = http://localhost:5000/project/us-central1/api

Axios.post(
 `${baseUrl}/v1/user/login`,
 { ...data },
 {
  headers: {
   Authorization: 'Basic auth...'
  }
 },
).then(r => console.log(r).catch(e =>console.log(e));
```

Now when i try to send request to my local firebase cloud function.
I get a 400 bad request.

[image: response]

after checking the request, I was wondering why it wasn't sending any preflight request, which it should do(to the best of my knowledge) but instead I saw a header named `Sec-Fetch-Mode`. I searched anywhere it's a bit abstract. And I can't seem to figure anything why my request still fails.

Is there anything Im missing in my config of `axios`?

My FE is running on a **VSCode Plugin** named `live server(http://127.0.0.1:5500)`

Also, my firebase cloud function has enabled `cors`

```
// cloud function expres app
cors({
 origin: true
})
```

Any insights would be very helpful.

Comment: Could be caused by your headers. Why you are using custom headers instead of ‘auth’ parameter?

Comment: @EvgeniiMalikov, what do you mean auth parameter?

Comment: @EvgeniiMalikov, sorry, I saw it on axios and tested it. they're just the same, it will just spit out `Authorization: Basic ..token`

Answer (score 57):

The `OPTIONS` request is actually being sent, because you are sending a cross-origin request with an `Authorization` header which is considered as non-simple. It doesn't show in developer tools because of a feature/bug in Chrome 76 & 77. See [Chrome not showing OPTIONS requests in Network tab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57410051) for more information.

The preflight request is a mechanism that allows to deny cross-origin requests on **browser side** if the server is not CORS aware (e.g: old and not maintained), or if it explicitly wants to deny cross-origin requests (in both cases, the server won't set the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header). What CORS does could be done on server side by checking the `Origin` header, but CORS actually protects the user at browser level. It blocks the disallowed cross-origin requests even before they are sent, thus reducing the network traffic, the server load, and preventing the old servers from receiving any cross-origin request by default.

On the other hand, `Sec-Fetch-Mode` is one of the [Fetch metadata headers](https://www.w3.org/TR/fetch-metadata/) (`Sec-Fetch-Dest`, `Sec-Fetch-Mode`, `Sec-Fetch-Site` and `Sec-Fetch-User`). These headers are meant to inform the **server** about the context in which the request has been sent. Based on this extra information, the server is then able to determine if the request looks legitimate, or simply deny it. They exist to help HTTP servers mitigate certain types of attacks, and are not related to CORS.

For example the good old `<img src="https://mybank.com/giveMoney?amount=9999999&to=evil@attacker.com">` attack could be detected on server side because the `Sec-Fetch-Dest` would be set to `"image"` (this is just a simple example, implying that the server exposes endpoints with the `GET` method with unsafe cookies for money operations which is obviously not the case in real life).

As a conclusion, fetch metadata headers are not designed to replace preflight requests, but rather to coexist with them since they fulfill different needs. And the 400 error has likely nothing to do with these, but rather with the request that does not comply with the endpoint specification.

Comment: @Mr. Flibble Can you please edit the original post so it focuses on the bounty? Or maybe take the bounty away? It was just a typo in the Javascript!

Comment: @santamanno,  it was a typo. it it was really a spread, as for the answer.
I really don't know why it happened(400 error). But, when I added, `responseType: json, and Cache-Control: no-cache, Content-Type: aplication/json` and it works.

Comment: Using `POST` is not sufficient to make a CORS request 'simple'. The custom header `Authorization` and the `Content-Type: application/json` shown in the question will both trigger a preflight OPTIONS request. The reason the preflight request was not shown in the developer tools is because of a feature/bug in Chrome 76 & 77. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57410051 for more information.

Comment: @skirtle thanks for pointing out that there are some non-simple headers that should trigger the preflight request. I'm editing my answer

Comment: Any idea what this header means: `Sec-Fetch-User: ?1` ? See related question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59860648/incoming-sec-fetch-user-1-header-messes-up-my-request-throttling

Answer (score -1):

You are missing a dot on your spread operator, this is the correct syntax:

{ ...data }

Note the three dots before “data”.

Please see the use of spread operators with objects here:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax