# Error when GET HTTPS from REST API in Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, https, http-headers

I have an Angular app running which uses an external api to get countries ISOs.
This API uses https and it's giving me an error.

The thing is: when I use a proxy in my angular local environment, mapping `/iso-api/` to the real url it works ok.

```
"/iso-api/*": {
    "target": "https://www...",
    "pathRewrite": { "^/iso-api": "" },
    "secure": false,
    "changeOrigin": true,
    "logLevel": "debug"
}
```

But I want this to work in production, so I want to use the real url.

In my server I am returning the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *` header already.

I've tried to run the angular server with ssl (as the external api uses https), but I receive the same error.

I know a solution would be to implement the proxy in the server, but I believe this should not be done and there may be a way to retrieve this data from the frontend.
Help please.

### Response

This is the network error in **Chrome**:
[image: browser network tab]

In **Firefox**, the request ends with 200 OK and returns data, but CORS error is thrown and I cannot access the data from the app: `CORS header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' missing`

**General**

```
Request URL: https://www...
Referrer Policy: no-referrer-when-downgrade
```

**Request headers**

```
:method: GET
:scheme: https
accept: application/json, text/plain, */*
accept-encoding: gzip, deflate, br
accept-language: es-ES,es;q=0.9,en;q=0.8
origin: http://localhost:4200
referer: http://localhost:4200/app/login
sec-fetch-dest: empty
sec-fetch-mode: cors
sec-fetch-site: cross-site
```

**Response headers**

```
accept-ranges: bytes
cache-control: max-age=0
content-encoding: gzip
content-language: en-US
content-length: 68356
content-type: application/json
date: Mon, 27 Apr 2020 14:49:30 GMT
expires: Mon, 27 Apr 2020 14:49:30 GMT
referrer-policy: strict-origin-when-cross-origin
server-timing: cdn-cache; desc=HIT
server-timing: edge; dur=1
server-timing: ACTT;dur=0,ACRTT;dur=88
set-cookie: ... expires=Mon, 27 Apr 2020 16:49:30 GMT; max-age=7200; path=/; domain=...; HttpOnly
set-cookie: ... Domain=...; Path=/; Expires=Mon, 27 Apr 2020 18:49:30 GMT; Max-Age=14400; HttpOnly
set-cookie: ... Domain=...; Path=/; Expires=Tue, 27 Apr 2021 14:49:30 GMT; Max-Age=31536000; Secure
status: 200
vary: Accept-Encoding
```

## UPDATE

Angular service code

```js
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';

...

constructor(
    private _http: HttpClient,
    private _errorUtil: ErrorUtilService,
    private _converter: StoreConverter
  ) {}

...
  getCountries(): Observable<CountryWithLanguages[]> {
    return this._http.get<GetStoresResponse>(API.storeUrl).pipe(
      catchError(this._errorUtil.handle),
      map(result => result.stores),
      switchMap(stores => stores),
      filter(this._isActiveStore),
      map(store => this._converter.toView(store)),
      toArray()
    );
  }
```

To serve the app I use angular dev server, I do not add the 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header manually but, in the browser, I see that it is being added.

[image: Chrome Network tab]

angular.json

```
"serve": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "push-web-app:build",
            "proxyConfig": "src/proxy-local.conf.json"
          },
         }
```

Comment: So you are calling your production API from your localhost server? It's a bit weird to have a err_failed error but still have response headers.. you have no other errors in the console?

Comment: So potentially dumb ask but have you tried using fetch or ajax? Just to see if you can pinpoint the exact location of the issue?

Comment: It's an open API, not a production app that I manage, it works when accessing to the url from the browser. No errors in the console, just that message in the network tab...

I've tried using fetch but the same happens. I think the problem is not with the http get request, but with the browser restricting cors

Comment: The weird thing is that for CORS error you normally have a clear error message. Are you using chrome? You did  not filter out warnings in the console?

Comment: Yes, I'm using Chrome but the console is pristine

Comment: If the console isn’t showing any errors, then you can rule out CORS.

Comment: You might want to try using Firefox devtools to inspect the request — because there are unfortunately a number of different cases in which Chrome devtools is no longer exposing certain request and response details. See https://stackoverflow.com/q/57410051/441757 for example.

Comment: Thanks @sideshowbarker, in Firefox the CORS error is thown, I've updated the question

Comment: I assume you are using the built-in `httpClient`? May we see the code for the HTTP call as well as how you construct the headers please?

Comment: Can you show how you send the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header server side? The error clearly says that this header is missing

Comment: I've updated the question with the code you requested :)

Comment: Did you check out [Access-Control-Expose-Headers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Access-Control-Expose-Headers)? This header enables other CORS header to be present in response. You can check it like this: `this.http.get<T>(url, { headers: {
                'Access-Control-Expose-Headers': 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin'
            }});`

Comment: Are you using ExpressJS for your API?

Comment: I don't really get what you are trying to do. You said 'In my server I am returning the Access-Control-Allow-Origin: * header already.', then in your update you said you were not. Are you trying to use angular's dev proxy in production mode? This is not a good idea. So the question is: do you have access to the server's API code? You need to set `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *` (or restrict it to your domain) server side if you want to get rid of that CORS error. Or create your own proxy

Comment: Just to be clear: I don't own the server and I can't add any headers from it. 

I am using angular dev server in local dev, the app will be deployed in a remote server.

Access-Control-Expose-Headers didn't work.

I'm not using express, just angular dev server.

@David proxy is a solution for local dev, but not for prod, that's the reason of my question. Thank you

Comment: Maybe what I ask can't be done without a custom server with a proxy

Comment: So the answer to your question is that you need to set up your own proxy in your production environment on your remote server. This is the only way to get around CORS if you do not own the API server. What kind of webserver are you using? Nginx?

Comment: Ok, thanks @David.  I know how to proxy from the server, just wanted to know if there was some workaround from the frontend.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't request a resource from another domain. This would be a security hole. You can read more here: [Same-origin policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Same-origin_policy)

Sending `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *` from your server won't give you access to the aforementioned API. The provider of this API needs to give you permission to access the API, you can't give yourself this permission.

The error you posted states that the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header is missing. It means that the API isn't sending this header.

There might be two reasons why this API isn't sending `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header.

1. A misconfiguration on the side of this API. In this case you have to ask the provider of this API to fix this issue.
2. The API provider is restricting access to the API on purpose. In this case you have to ask the provider of this API to give you access from your domain.

You can also proxy the request through your server. The core difference when using proxy is that your server reads the resource from the API and not the client browser. See [David's response](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61636482/5591753) on how to configure proxy with nginx.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot bypass CORS browser side. If you are not able to modify the server side, your only solution is to use a proxy.

For development purposes, you can use angular's built-in proxy server, but not for production.

Here is a basic nginx config to do this

```
server {
    listen          80;
    server_name     yourdomain.com; #domain where your angular code is deployed

    location /iso-api{

        RewriteRule                     ^/iso-api/(.*)$ /$1 break;
        proxy_pass                      https://thirdpartyapidomain.com; #url of the API you are trying to access
    }

    location
    {
        #Your normal angular location
        #try_files ...
    }
}
```

This will redirects requests like

`http://yourdomain.com/iso-api/countriesList` to `https://thirdpartyapidomain.com/countriesList`;

Since now client and server API calls are on the same domain, you should not have CORS issues

Comment: To be exact you should say "You cannot bypass same-origin policy browser side" instead of "You cannot bypass CORS browser side". CORS is as method of relaxing same-origin policy.

Answer (score 0):

Use this site to resolve the CORS error:
https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/

Use Exemple
https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/https://freegeoip.app/json

```
this._http.get('https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/https://freegeoip.app/json')
```

It's just a workaround but it works. Use it even just to understand if the error is related to CORS or something else.

Comment: Thanks, but I need a strong solution. I am trying to find a solution in the frontend. As I wrote in the question: I know a solution would be to implement the proxy in the server, but I believe this should not be done and there may be a way to retrieve this data from the frontend.

Answer (score 0):

Try the .get call with option **`withCredentials: true`**:

```js
return this._http.get<GetStoresResponse>(API.storeUrl, { withCredentials: true }).pipe();
```

...and/or making sure your browsers are up to date.

Comment: The request does not need authorization. 

I've tried it anyway and it didn't work.

Comment: I figured, but there's been some precedent in other cases where a required cert was passed via _withCredentials_ -- was worth a shot. Good luck!